# Unable to read 'Offline' files in .NET

Tags: c#, io

I'm accessing network share which employs the concept of 'Offline' files (they appear with a tiny X on the icon).

When clicking open the file via Windows Explorer, these files seem to magically populate themselves with the correct data.

However, when trying to read the contents programmatically, I just get a load of a ASCII meta data:

```
File.ReadAllText(@"X:\SomeDrive\SomeFile.xml");
[AC6E011E9160334d82F4262648B16B9C]\r\n;a=BwAA37F/DFcLVAQC157CExNUBAN (and so on...)
```

Can anyone offer any solutions or ideas? My google-fu is lacking on this one.

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693228/is-it-possible-to-use-microsofts-offline-files-api-in-c) can help you out a bit?